# How to distinguish between a Prolog Interpreter and Prolog Compiler written in Java?

Tags: prolog

Is it possible to distinguish between a Prolog Interpreter and Prolog Compiler from its usage or intermediary files generated?

Wikipedia has a good compilation of Prolog implementations
       http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Prolog_implementations

This is a question about the notation used in table.

Does the column "Compiled Code" means that the corresponding Prolog is implemented with a Prolog Compiler?

(I am not sure if stackoverflow is a good place to ask about this. If not, please let me know, I will remove this thread.)

Comment: which prolog compiler?

Comment: @Leo How about SWI-Prolog, XSB, Prova, JIProlog, and YAP-Prolog?

Comment: the only way to discover that is inspecting these intermediary files

Comment: @Leo The problem is that those intermediary files can be generated in any place on the local disk, and can be removed instantly. This makes it not easy to identify between a Prolog Interpreter and Prolog Compiler.

Comment: you need an open source implementation so you can control this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Compiled Code" in this table means that any given Prolog program is *itself* compiled by the respective Prolog system, and the compiled form is executed.

Most of these systems compile Prolog programs to *abstract machine code* before executing it. Examples of abstract machines for Prolog (like the JVM for Java) are the WAM, ZIP, TOAM etc.

Some of these systems even compile Prolog code to native machine code, for example via JIT compilation, just like Java systems can compile Java code to native machine code.

In practice, you usually do *not* create intermediary files when working with Prolog: You run the Prolog system, load your source file, and the system compiles the file *on the fly* and *in memory* to abstract machine code, without creating an intermediary file. You usually can create such files manually if you need them, but you typically do not.

Thus, the creation of intermediary files is *not* a criterion that lets you distinguish a compiler from an interpreter.

Comment: And I guess there is GNU Prolog, which lets you compile to native code, but I don't know if this is what OP was asking.

Comment: @mat Does that mean almost all Prolog systems listed below are implemented with a Prolog Compiler instead of an interpreter?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Prolog_implementations

Comment: Yes. Almost all Prolog systems I am aware of *compile* Prolog code, at least to some intermediary code, and the run the compiled code instead of the source code.

Comment: @mat Could you please give a comment about Prova:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213929/is-the-prova-implemented-with-a-prolog-compiler-or-prolog-interpreter