# Is the Prova implemented with a Prolog compiler or Prolog interpreter?

Tags: prolog, logic-programming

I am looking at the Java-written Prolog system, Prova.
https://prova.ws/

But it is not clear about its implementation, a Prolog compiler or Prolog interpreter? I read the manual, but did not found an answer.

Comment: without java sources, it's impossible to say...

Comment: Why do you think that this Prova system is a Prolog system?

Comment: The user manual indicates (a) it's not a Prolog implementation, but a language loosely based upon logic programming, and (b) that it's a script-based language (interpreted rather than compiled - there are no instructions in the manual for compilation).

Comment: At first glance, given some operator declaration (hidden to us), a file.prova should be read(able) in Prolog. Then maybe they use Prolog internally, to interpret their knowledge base.

Answer (score 0):

There are some rumors that Prova is based on Mandarax. The newest
version seem to be heading in the same direction as SWI-Prolog 7,
i.e. it supports dicts and a dot notation. See also here:

http://prova.ws/confluence/display/REWRITEDEV/Prova+maps+for+defining+slotted+terms

The original Mandarax seems to have been an interpreter, and 
in the user manual of Prova we find one sentence that self 
declares it as a Prolog interpreter, but no hint for compilation.

But there seems to be a newer version of Mandarax (1.1.0) which was
some kind of compiler, but maybe Prova was already branched out
before the compiler arrived, and its still an interpeter.

So although it self declares as a Prolog interpreter, it is most
likely not an ISO Prolog systems, since for example op/3 is missing.
I guess it uses aa tokenizer with some hard wired operators and a 
parser with some hard wired operator expressions. (*)

It might nevertheless offer some goodies, but judging from the
documentation and binary size, they might not be many. Which 
is possibly compensated by the ability to directly embed Java
calls by the dot notation:

http://prova.ws/confluence/display/REWRITEDEV/Calling+Java+from+Prova+rulebases

Bye

(*)
The Prova syntax goes even that far, that it requires the end-user
to write fail() instead of fail. A syntax variant that is also
found in the new SWI-Prolog 7, although not with the same drastic
effect on the end-user that he/she would be not anymore allowed to use 
atoms as goals.